# Merge conditions in if statement

Tags: logical-operators, boolean-expression

I have two conditions for if statement. I found that those are different, but I don't know the reason.

```
1: if ((local != -1) || (fall_back == 1))
2. if ((local != -1) || ((local != -1) && (fall_back == 1)))
```

Those two are different. But in Math, we have  `A V (B ^ C) = (A V B) ^ (A V C)`. If I use this equation and reorganize statement 2, it seems to be the same as 1. Is there anything fundamental I am missing?
How can I simplify statement 2? It doesn't look good.

Comment: This isn't really a C question; it's a basic logic question.

Comment: In second case if condtion `(local != -1)` fail then no meaning to check second condition it will also failed.

Comment: Statement 2 isn't really `A V (B ^ C) = (A V B) ^ (A V C)`; it's `A V (A ^ B) = (A V A) ^ (A V B)`

Answer (score 0):

In Logical OR if the first condition is true means it wont evaluate the second one! But in Logical AND first condition false means it wont evaluate the second one!

```
if ((local != -1) || (fall_back == 1))
```

In this if any one of the condition is true, `local != -1` or `fall_back == 1` it will evaluate the body of the `if`.

```
if ((local != -1) || ((local != -1) && (fall_back == 1)))
```

But here both should be true, Then only it will evaluate the expression. else `local != -1` fails means, Both conditions will fails. Because Logical AND(`&&`) both should be true!

Consider- `local != -1` is false and `fall_back == 1` is true

```
if ( false || true ) -> if(0 || 1) -->true

if ( false || (false && true)) -> if(0 || (0 && 1)) -> if(0 || 0) --> false
```

Answer (score 0):

Short circuit evaluation is done in order to optimize.
So in an expression like `(A!=B) || (A!=C)`, if `A!=B` turns out to be true the second part `A!=C` is not evaluated at all, because independent of the second part, the expression will turn out to be true.

Answer (score 0):

Consider

```
A -> local != -1
B -> fall_back == 1
```

Your first condition reduces to

```
A V B
```

And second statement reduces to

```
A V (A ^ B)  =>  A ^ (1 V B)  => A
```

So your first statement requires either condition A or B to be true
And second statement tests only if A is true

Consider test case where `local = 0` and `fall_back = 1`

```
Statement 1 => True as fall_back == 1
Statement 2 => False as local != 0
```

Hence conditions are not the same

Answer (score 0):

This is Simple, If you Take `local != -1` = true and `fall_back == 1` = false
Then in Both case result will be true because the value of `local != -1` = true

but if take `local != -1` = false and `fall_back == 1` = true 
then in first case result will be true and in second case result will be false.